# A strange feature of node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Noticed a strange feature of `node.js`.

**For example:**

Let's say, I've got some variable on `node.js` server: `var user_id = '1';`, in which the stored user id which is connected to the server.

`user1` have `var user = 1;`

`user2` have `var user = 2;`

...

`user99` have `var user = 99;`

But if at some point I will demand from the server variable `user` - I will return the id of the last user who rewrote her.

Is that right? So it should be?
I thought, `node.js` for each user creates a `flow/process` ...

*Thanks for your answer!*

**index.js**

```
dNode({
    connect: function(data, callback) {
        IM.iUserId = data.user_id;
        IM.start();
    }
});
```

**im.js**

```
var IM = {
    iUserId: false,
    start: function() {
        console.log(this.iUserId);
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your code, so we can see in which scope this variable is defined?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474808/node-js-understanding-variable-scopes

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi look my edit.

Comment: Looks like you've got one global "IM" object.

Comment: @Pointy `var IM = require('./im.js');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you have **one** global `IM` objects that **all** of your connections are sharing.

---

You can set/get a value for each socket by using `socket.set` and `socket.get`

Comment: Yes. `var IM = require('./im.js');`

Comment: @RomanGorbatko exactly. Therefore you keepupdating the **same** object

Comment: :) I understand that, if it possible for each user to have a user variable with its own value?

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is single thread one context, it **does not** create any isolated context for users like in PHP.

Everything inside is shared and cross-acessible.

Comment: I mean, if I use `socket.io` as the transport between the client and `node.js` - I need to do something like: `var users[socket.id] = {'user_id': data.user_id}` ?

Comment: Yes, it is one object, so it is shared, so you have to separate stuff. It actually makes it cool, when you want to exchange things between clients - as it is shared, you don't need any database or whats so ever (middle guy) to exchange data, you just send it directly.